# Regex URL between /

Tags: regex

I have a url that looks like this: 
www.example.com/website/link1/link2/link3

Which regex expression can I use to only get link3?

I found something similar but can't get it to work. I need to ignore the www.example.com/website/

```
 ^\/[^/]+\/([^/]+)\/
```

Comment: Why not just split on `/` and take the last part?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL doesn't end in a slash, so you can simply capture the last chunk of content leading up to the final trailing slash:

```
/([^\/]+)$/
```

Note that you need the `\` before the `/` to escape it, since it's embedded in `/` wrappers and some environments won't allow the embedded `/` without a preceding `\`.

If you need to support a trailing slash, you can add `\/?` ("an optional slash") before the `$`.

An example demo of this regex (with a useful explanation about it) can be found here:  https://regex101.com/r/hRR4rw/1

Comment: What about link2?

Comment: Just add a suitable prefix to capture it, again going backward from the end of the string:  `/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/`

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just anchor to the end:

```
/([^/]+)\/?$/
```

Where that matches `/link/example/` as well as `/link/example` and returns `example` in both cases.